# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG Using Nginx reverse proxy and certbot

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following Nginx config:

```
erver {
    server_name api.wijdenbos.ch www.api.wijdenbos.ch;

    location /akira/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.wijdenbos.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.wijdenbos.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

In my app I have a route pointing to https://api.wijdenbos.ch/akira/auth/login but when I visit the page, I am getting `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`, SSL is working because if I visit the regular domain https://api.wijdenbos.ch/ I see the Nginx starting page with HTTPS enabled, why am I getting this error when visiting the route?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nginx. Can add details on what software are you running on `http://localhost:4000` (something using node.js I'd guess? This software sends incorrect redirects to URLs starting with `https://api.wijdenbos.ch:4000`, which are obviously wrong.

Comment: Yes it is a Node.js Express app, I have no idea where the port is appended, I did not set that up myself anywhere, my app setup is available at https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/blob/master/packages/bot/src/index.ts @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the wild redirections that your Node.js Express app returns. When you first posted it redirected everything to `https://api.wijdenbos.ch:4000`, which gave the error: that port uses HTTP, not SSL.

When running an app behind a forward proxy (it doesn't matter which framework/technology uses the app), you have some configuration to do. Cf. [Express behind proxies](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) for your specific case. In **nginx** you'll have to set the headers required by Express:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
```

Besides you probably want to get rid of:

```
if (NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(forceSSL);
}
```

in your app which causes wild redirections: it redirects to `https`, but it is not configured so it redirects to the same port.

**Remark:** Bind your app to `localhost`, so it is available only through **nginx**:

```
app.listen(4000, 'localhost', () => {
    logger.info("Express server is listening on port 4000");
});
```

**Edit**: After a short look at [your code](https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/blob/master/packages/bot/src/services/discord/api.ts), it seems that you want to rewrite `https://api.wijdenbos.ch/akira/auth/login` to `http://localhost:4000/auth/login`. Just now you are passing the request URI unchanged due to a missing slash:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
```

Comment: I have updated the code and edited the question to include the new config but without success, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I want to make this app only work on /akira so I can have other apps for other directories, basically /appname - I can not wrap my head around the Nginx config, what would I have to change to get this behaviour? It would be nice to have a working example for this for the future

Comment: Add a `/` character after `4000` or rewrite the URLs in your app to contain a prefix of `/akira`.

Comment: And also a slash to `location /akira/` :-)

Comment: I changed to `location /akira/` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;`, left everything else untouched, the error from the initial question is gone but for some reason the port still gets added, will change the config in the question to reflect the changes

Comment: Your browser remembers permanent redirects, restart it. Or use something like `curl -i https://api.wijdenbos.ch/akira/auth/login`

Comment: Thanks for all the help! seems to work fine now