# Session not set using Nginx reverse proxy with Express

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Express server with the following config:

```
if (NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.set("trust proxy", 1);
}

app.use(
  session({
    store: new SQLiteStore({
      db: "database.sqlite",
      concurrentDB: true
    }),
    secret: SESSION_SECRET!,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      domain:
        NODE_ENV === "production" ? "akira-bot.netlify.com" : "localhost",
      secure: NODE_ENV === "production",
      httpOnly: true
    }
  })
);
```

My Nginx config looks like

```
location /akira/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
}
```

When redirect from an external auth service, no session is set https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fakira-bot.netlify.com%2Fdashboard&scope=identify%20guilds&client_id=647860115239731220 what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are usually maintained through cookies, which are sent only to the domain specified in the cookie. According to your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/994489), `akira-bot.netlify.com` is not the domain name of your server. So modify this part:

```
cookie: {
  domain:
    NODE_ENV === "production" ? "akira-bot.netlify.com" : "localhost",
  secure: NODE_ENV === "production",
  httpOnly: true
}
```

Remark: if a cookie is set as **secure**, it is sent only when connecting through SSL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, I tried to set it to api.wijdenbos.ch and then wijdenbos.ch but both do not seem to work, no session is being set, the connection is over SSL

Comment: Read the [session manual](https://github.com/expressjs/session). My guess is: if `saveUnitialized` is `true` Express sets a cookie, otherwise it waits until the session is explicitly saved in code. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) might be a better place for this kind of details.