# Multiple virtual hosts HTTPS on nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to have multiple (two) virtual hosts (sites/applications) both over HTTPS on a single instance of Nginx?

I have tried something like

```
upstream a {
  server app:8080;
}


upstream b {
  server app2:5678;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name sub.example.com;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam           /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;
  
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

server {
  listen 5678 ssl http2;
  server_name sub.example.com;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam           /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;
  
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn2;
}
}
```

The app 'a' is accessible. However, app 'b' is not. I get an `Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

The two apps should run on the same subdomain.

Comment: the shown config does not meat the error. what are you hiding?

Comment: @djdomi thanks for your reply. I have added the whole config file.

Comment: still not showing, whats port 8080, 5678 and whats unicorn - you still hide relevant information. remember about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081239/error-code-ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-on-nginx-ubuntu-server or shortly said: somekind of application running as https and is decleared as http

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL\_ERROR\_RX\_RECORD\_TOO\_LONG Using Nginx reverse proxy and certbot](https://serverfault.com/questions/994489/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-using-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-certbot)